# How can we add sound on an image with link?

Tags: html, image, audio, hyperlink

I was trying to add sound on an image with link in it...when the image will be clicked, first the sound will be produced and then link will open... it only worked with sound but didnt not with both the sound and the link...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to answer without you showing your current code and what you have tried. To me it sounds like you have the audio working and your html is probably similar to:

```
    <input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="../sounds/the-sound.mp3"></audio>
```

I would try something like this:

Javascript:

```
    function playAudio(url) {
      new Audio(url).play();
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <img src="image.jpg" onclick="playAudio('the-sound.mp3')">
```

And enclose that img tag with a anchor tag. Don't forget to add a

```
    target="_blank"
```

so it opens in a new tab rather than leaving the webpage.